# node-webkit Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-webkit

I received this error:

```
Error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:73:15)
    at Receiver.self._receiver.onerror (C:\programing\project\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:566:10)
    at Receiver.error (C:\programing\project\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:301:8)
    at Receiver.processPacket (C:\programing\project\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:198:12)
    at Receiver.add (C:\programing\project\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:89:3)
    at Socket.firstHandler (C:\programing\project\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:524:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

node-webkit seems to run for up to 2 to 4 hours, then I receive that error stated above.  I am not sure if my wifly module is timing out causing a premature disconnect while the node-webkit is attempting to send a packet back to the wifly module.  Or if the the packet being sent over web-socket protocal-76 is corrupt causing the webkit module to not understanding what is being sent?  What should I do to fix this error?

websocket code:

```
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, wss = new WebSocketServer({
        port : 8080
    });
    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
        alert('connected!');
        ws.on('message', function(message) {
            //alert(message);
            $('#wsData').val(message);
            //console.log('received: %s', message);
        });
        ws.send('something', function(error){
            alert('Send error' + error);
        });
    });
```

After adding:

```
ws.on('error', function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

I receive the message: reserved fields must be empty index.html:50
Line 50 code: `console.log(error);`

Comment: You have to catch the `error` event: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/476

Comment: @Blender, ok.  to catch the error, should I do something like:  ws.on('error', function(error) {
console.log(error);
});

Comment: Probably. Try it out.

Comment: @Blender, I did.  I shall see what the outcome is a few hours from now.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Blender, I updated my first post.